# laravel,how i can change the code to return an array?

Tags: php, laravel

i have this controller which access the pivot table in many to many relationships. the columns in the pivot table are values and created_at. i want this controller to return me an array of values and created_at

```
public function status($s_type)
{

    $o_health_status = Status::where('name', 'health')->first();
    $o_speed_status = Status::where('name', 'speed')->first();

    if ($s_type === 'health'){

        $o_response = $this->statuses()->where('status_id', $o_health_status->id)
        ->select('values','created_at')->orderBy('created_at','ASC')->first();

        if($o_response === null){
            return 'unsigned';
        }
        $o_response = $o_response->values;
        return $o_response;         
    }else{

        $o_response = $this->statuses()->where('status_id', $o_speed_status->id)
        ->select('values','created_at')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
        if($o_response === null){
            return 'unsigned';
        }

        $o_response = $o_response->values;
        return $o_response;


    }
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In laravel, if you need to return an array from the query, you can use `pluck()` instead of `select()`

```
$o_response = $this->statuses()->where('status_id', $o_health_status->id)
    ->pluck('values','created_at')->orderBy('created_at','ASC');// ->first();
//I think you no need to use ->first(); here.
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#retrieving-results) (scroll down to *Retrieving A List Of Column Values*)

Comment: for same reason, when i wrote the code you suggested. it gave me error that says, Method orderBy does not exist! . are you allowed to use pluck and orderdBy at the same time?

Comment: normally the resultant array comming according to the values having in the database. if they are ordered, then nothing to worry.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use pluck for this. this will pluck all required elements from a collection: so I clean up a bit and should looks something like this:

```
public function status($s_type)
{

    $o_health_status = Status::where('name', 'health')->first();
    $o_speed_status = Status::where('name', 'speed')->first();
    $o_response = $s_type === 'health' ? $this->statuses()->pluck('values','created_at')->where('status_id', $o_health_status->id)
            ->select('values', 'created_at')->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->first() : $this->statuses()->pluck('values','created_at')->where('status_id', $o_speed_status->id)
            ->select('values', 'created_at')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();

    return ! $o_response ? 'unsigned' : $o_response->values;
}
```

Comment: for same reason, your code looks perfect, but when i replaced my code with your code. it doesnt work at all.

Comment: if its not working., why you marked as the answer? please check again.